# How can I recreate 'dir' for shelve db

Tags: python-3.x, shelve

Everyday I store data to one shelve file . Today I discovered some last keys missing. The dat-file size is not changed. The dir file and the bak file contains all keys except some last keys. How can I recreate this files, or how can I rescan my dat file and restore all stored items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by hex editor and hands. There is simple steps:

1. open dat file with hex editor.
2. open our dir file
3. find data offset. It should be 0. This is offset 1. [Fig 1](https://yadi.sk/i/53a4nmGjxkAbK)
4. find block of ten zero and find the offset at start of this block. This is offset 2. [Fig 2](https://yadi.sk/i/cZMYD1ywxkBNA)
5. substract offset 1 from offset 2. In my case it be 71768182 - 0 = 71768182. This is data length.
6. We should write to dir file:
   `'1', (0, 71768182)`

   - 1 - key of this item in our db.
   - 0 - offset of start datablock
   - 71768182 - length of datablock;
7. Go to start of the new datablock. [Fig 3](https://yadi.sk/i/eAnv8OOMxkDSq)
8. Go to step 3